# Error during deserialize JSON windows phone 8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I got a api that returns this JSON code:

```
 [{"startDate":1409553000000,
   "endDate":1409570100000,
   "moduleCode":"#SPLUS0EBB2C",
   "activityDescription":"User Interface Design (Tjuna)","staffMembers":[],
   "locations":[{"id":"E404A902125255D3330455204193CC29","name":"HAA-H1-21","key":"14124","capacity":24,"url":null,"avoidConcurrencyLocationIds":[]}],
   "studentSets":["INF3s","INF4a"],
   "activityTypeName":"Other","activityTypeDescription":null,"notes":null,"highlighted":false,
   "timetableKeys":["2013!studentsetgroup!9EEA55042B995043A2BC5739BF428E07"]}]
```

To deserialize I have this code:

```
var responseObject = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Apicalls.Rooster>(json);



class Rooster
{
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string activityDescription { get; set; }
    public locations[] locations { get; set; }
    public string studentSets { get; set; }
}
public class locations
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Everytime I try to deserialize it gives a error that it's not possible to deserialize the json code. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Next time you can go to http://json2csharp.com/ to generate property class of a JSON doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rooster**

```
public class Rooster
{
    public long startDate { get; set; }
    public long endDate { get; set; }
    public string moduleCode { get; set; }
    public string activityDescription { get; set; }
    public List<object> staffMembers { get; set; }
    public List<Location> locations { get; set; }
    public List<string> studentSets { get; set; }
    public string activityTypeName { get; set; }
    public object activityTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public object notes { get; set; }
    public bool highlighted { get; set; }
    public List<string> timetableKeys { get; set; }
}
```

**Location**

```
public class Location
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public int capacity { get; set; }
    public object url { get; set; }
    public List<object> avoidConcurrencyLocationIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**

```
var responseObject = 
             await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<Apicalls.Rooster>>(json);
```

**[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M5sXzq)**